# Templating with Linux in a Shell Script?

Tags: linux, shell

What I want to acomplish is:

1. Having a config file as template, with variables like $version $path (for example apache config)
2. Having a shell script that "fills in" the variables of the template and writes the generated file to disk.

Is this possible with a shell script. I would be very thankfull if you can name some commands/tools I can accomplish this or some good links.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is very possible.  A very simple way to implement this would be for the template file to actually be the script and use shell variables such as

```
#! /bin/bash
version="1.2.3"
path="/foo/bar/baz"
cat > /tmp/destfile <<-EOF
here is some config for version $version which should
also reference this path $path
EOF
```

You could even make this configurable on the command line by specifying `version=$1` and `path=$2`, so you can run it like `bash script /foo/bar/baz 1.2.3`. The `-` before EOF causes whitespace before the lines be ignored, use plain `<<EOF` if you do not want that behavior.

Another way to do this would be to use the search and replace functionality of sed

```
#! /bin/bash
version="1.2.3"
path="/foo/bar/baz"
sed -e "s/VERSION/$version/g" -e "s/PATH/$path/" /path/to/templatefile > /tmp/destfile
```

which would replace each instance of the strings VERSION and PATH.  If there are other reasons those strings would be in the template file you might make your search and replace be *VERSION* or %VERSION% or something less likely to be triggered accidentally.

Comment: This will become much more challenging if your variables contain newlines

Comment: To escape dollar sign in the template, use backslash: `\$`

Answer (score 60):

The easiest way to do this simply in Linux CLI is to use [`envsubst`](https://manpage.me/?q=envsubst) and Environment Variables.

Example template file `apache.tmpl`:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:${PORT}>
    ServerName ${SERVER_NAME}
    ServerAlias ${SERVER_ALIAS}
    DocumentRoot "${DOCUMENT_ROOT}"
</VirtualHost>
```

Run `envsubst` and output result to new file `my_apache_site.conf`:

```sh
export PORT="443"
export SERVER_NAME="example.com"
export SERVER_ALIAS="www.example.com"
export DOCUMENT_ROOT="/var/www/html/"
envsubst < apache.tmpl > my_apache_site.conf
```

Output:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's part of GNU gettext, and therefore available on all major Unix platforms (including macOS X), as well as Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 27):

No tools necessary other than `/bin/sh`. Given a template file of the form

```
Version: ${version}
Path: ${path}
```

or even with mixed shell code included

```
Version: ${version}
Path: ${path}
Cost: ${cost}\$
$(i=1; for w in one two three four; do echo Param${i}: ${w}; i=$(expr $i + 1); done)
```

and a shell parsable configuration file like

```
version="1.2.3-r42"
path="/some/place/under/the/rainbow/where/files/dance/in/happiness"
cost="42"
```

it is a simple matter to expand this to

```
Version: 1.2.3-r42
Path: /some/place/under/the/rainbow/where/files/dance/in/happiness
Cost: 42$
Param1: one
Param2: two
Param3: three
Param4: four
```

Indeed, given the path to the configuration file in shell variable `config_file` and the path to the template file in `template_file`, all you need to do is:

```
. ${config_file}
template="$(cat ${template_file})"
eval "echo \"${template}\""
```

This is perhaps prettier than having complete shell script as the template file (@mtinberg's solution).

The complete naive template expander program:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROG=$(basename $0)

usage()
{
    echo "${PROG} <template-file> [ <config-file> ]"
}

expand()
{
    local template="$(cat $1)"
    eval "echo \"${template}\""
}

case $# in
    1) expand "$1";;
    2) . "$2"; expand "$1";;
    *) usage; exit 0;;
esac
```

This will output the expansion to standard output; just redirect standard output to a file or modify the above in obvious fashion to produce the desired output file.

**Caveats:** Template file expansion would not work if the file contained unescaped double quotes (`"`). For security reasons, we should probably include some obvious sanity checks or, even better, perform shell escaping transformation if the template file is generated by external entity.

Comment: It is great to still see folks actively using shell scripts to do fun stuff like this.  A buddy of mine wrote a clock in shell script.  https://github.com/tablespoon/fun/blob/master/cli-clock  Fun times indeed.

Comment: When I found this answer when looking to do this myself, I implemented the pretty naive approach and posted it on Github: https://github.com/nealian/bash-unsafe-templates

Answer (score 5):

If you want lightweight and real templates rather than shell code that generates new files, the usual choices are `sed`& `awk` or `perl`.  Here is one link: http://savvyadmin.com/generate-text-from-templates-scripts-and-csv-data/

Me, I'd use a real language like perl, tcl, python, ruby or something else in that class. Something built for scripting. They all have good, simple templating tools and tons of examples in google.

Answer (score 4):

You probably ought to look into a configuration management system like [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) or [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/). These can easily do what you describe above and *much* more.

Comment: thanks. Absolutely, I have Chef installed and running. But it adds a lot of overhead, when you have to write your own cookbooks. I do not know the ruby programming language and my conclusion was. its easier to do this with a shell script for the easier cases (if possible).

Comment: Looks like [Puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html) and [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Templates) both use ERB for templates, and that's ridiculously easy to get started with. Given a variable `name`, the string `<%= name %>` in a template will get replaced with `name`'s value. How you define `name` outside the template differs between the two systems, obviously.

Comment: Yes templating (With Chef) itself is absolutely easy. But using chef as Framework (and writing the cookbooks) requires a lot of time. To get the data into the templates you need to understand where and how Chef manages the "merging" of datasources and a lot of other stuff. I have started writing my own cookbooks, but a shell script would in my special case be 100 times faster...

Comment: Getting the infrastructure going for Chef or Puppet can be a pain or you can try to figure out how to run them headless which is a fun adventure.  Ansible works fine in pull or push mode out of the box so it might strike a better balance of figuring it out and scripting it yourself.  http://docs.ansible.com/template_module.html

Answer (score 4):

I use [shtpl](https://github.com/zstegi/shtpl) for that. (private project of mine, which means, it is not widely in use. But maybe you want to test it anyway)

For example you want to generate an /etc/network/interfaces out of a csv-file, you can do it like that:

CSV-file content (here test.csv):

```
eth0;10.1.0.10;255.255.0.0;10.1.0.1
eth1;192.168.0.10; 255.255.255.0;192.168.0.1
```

Template (here interfaces.tpl):

```
#% IFS=';'
#% while read "Val1" "Val2" "Val3" "Val4"; do
auto $Val1 
iface $Val1 inet static
  address $Val2 
  netmask $Val3 
  gateway $Val4 

#% done < "$CSVFILE"
```

Command:

```
$ CSVFILE=test.csv sh -c "$( shtpl interfaces.tpl )"
```

Result:

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.1.0.10 
  netmask 255.255.0.0 
  gateway 10.1.0.1 

auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.0.10 
  netmask  255.255.255.0 
  gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I improved FooF's answer so that the user doesn't need to unescape double quotes manually:

```
#!/bin/bash
template="$(cat $1)"
template=$(sed 's/\([^\\]\)"/\1\\"/g; s/^"/\\"/g' <<< "$template")
eval "echo \"${template}\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Blatant Promotion Ahead

So while researching existing shell-based template engines, I came across this post.

I'd like to throw my creation into the ring for consideration:

> Bash-TPL | https://github.com/TekWizely/bash-tpl
>
> A smart, lightweight shell script templating engine, written in Bash
>
> Bash-TPL lets you you mark up textual files (config files, yaml, xml, scripts, html, etc) with shell commands and variable replacements, while minimally impacting your original file layout.
>
> Templates are compiled into shell scripts that you can invoke (along with variables, arguments, etc) to generate complete and well-formatted output text files.

So in the context of the OP's question, a template might look like this:

*test.tpl*

```
Version: <% $version %>
Path: <% $path %>
```

A simple example of executing the template with some data:

```
$ version="v1.0.0" path="/path/to/the/thing" source <( bash-tpl test.tpl )

Version: v1.0.0
Path: /path/to/the/thing
```

This simple example is just to show how [Bash-TPL](https://github.com/TekWizely/bash-tpl) can answer the OP's question.

The template engine itself supports many more features.

I hope you'll give it a try if you're in the market for a smart, easy to use shell script template engine.

Comment: This is a GREAT little bit of shell code!  It only took a few minutes to use it to create a complex Dockerfile template that made it SO more readable and easy to maintain.  The .INCLUDE directive is particularly handy and can be used to create complex "nested" templates/code.  If you are strictly working in Bash then really stop looking,  just use this, forget about all the other templating possiblites.

Answer (score 1):

I am probably late to this party. However, I stumbled about the very same problem and I opted for creating my own BASH template engine in a few lines of code:

Lets say that you have this `file.template`:

```
# My template
## Author
 - @NAME@ <@EMAIL@>
```

And this `rules` file:

```
NAME=LEOPOLDO WINSTON
EMAIL=leothewinston\@leoserver.com
```

You execute this command:

```
templater rules < file.template
```

You get this:

```
# My template
## Author
 - LEOPOLDO WINSTON <leothewinston@leoserver.com>
```

You can install it by:

```
 bpkg install vicentebolea/bash-templater
```

This is the project [site](https://github.com/vicentebolea/bash-templater)

Answer (score 1):

I recently published a bash script that accomplishs just that using a jinja-like template syntax. It's called [cookie](https://github.com/bbugyi200/cookie). Here's a demo:

[image: cookie demo]

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @RalfFriedl I'm not sure what you mean. I just reread the question thinking I must have missed something, but I'm not seeing it. In fact, how does this *not* answer *any* part of the question that was asked? It's almost like I built cookie with the sole purpose of answering this question... which I kindof did, though I may have worded it a bit differently in my head at the time.  :)

Comment: I'm a little late to play mediator, but perhaps Ralf was just charitably prompting you to _explain_ how cookie answers the question, rather than trying to uncharitably imply you don't know your own project well enough to judge whether it might solve someone's problem.

Comment: Is it just me, or those animated gifs are almost impossible to follow?.. At least you need to watch them several times. No way to stop, move backwards. Experience akin to the marquee tag.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @FooF's great answer (newlines didn't format in comment), using a heredoc + control characters, you can permit arbitrary characters *and* filenames:

```sh
template() {
    # if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] ; then return; fi # or just error
    eval "cat <<$(printf '\x04\x04\x04');
$(cat $1)
"
}
```

This accepts any non-null character, and only truncates early if 3 `^D` bytes are encountered on their own line (realistically never).  zsh even supports null terminators, so `printf '\x00\x00\x00'` would work.  `template` even works for treacherous filenames like:

```sh
for num in `seq 10`; do
    template 'foo "$ .html' # works
done
```

Beware shell templates can "expand" arbitrary commands, e.g. `$(launch_nukes.sh --target $(curl -sL https://freegeoip.app/csv/ | cut -d, -f 9,10))`.  With great power…

Edit: if you really don't want your files launching nukes at you, just `sudo -u nobody sh` (or some other safe user) beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I may be able to pique your interest on a script above all other scripts that have, thus far, been suggested here.

Given a template.txt:

```
Hello, {{person}}!
```

Kindly execute:

```sh
$ person=Bob ./render template.txt
```

And you shall see the output

```
Hello, Bob!
```

You may write it to a file by redirecting stdout as follows:

```sh
$ person=Bob ./render template.txt > rendered.txt
```

Or declare your variables in a file and then source it. This is best done inside a script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source ./myvalues
./render template.txt > rendered.txt
```

An advantage of said renderer above all the others is that it does not expand any variables such as `$foo` or `${bar}` which is quite useful if what you are endeavoring to render is, itself, a script! Furthermore, said renderer is unit tested and has received pull requests from the community.

I have been told that I must declare that I have written this script myself. Thus, I shall mention that I wrote it and is available in GitHub at https://github.com/relaxdiego/renderest

Some script stats if that interests you:

```
-------------------------
| Effective LOCs |  20  |
| Test Coverage  | 100% |
| Test LOCs      |  50  |
-------------------------
```

Comment: You should disclose that you wrote this script. And maybe write your answer a little more ... professionally.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider done! Thank you for reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

I created a shell templating script also named [`shtpl`](https://github.com/mlorenzo-stratio/shtpl) (just like [zstegi](https://serverfault.com/a/440733/310624), I didn't know, sorry!). My `shtpl` uses a jinja-like syntax which, now that I use ansible a lot, I'm pretty familiar with:

```
$ cat /tmp/test
{{ aux=4 }}
{{ myarray=( a b c d ) }}
{{ A_RANDOM=$RANDOM }}
$A_RANDOM
{% if $(( $A_RANDOM%2 )) == 0 %}
$A_RANDOM is even
{% else %}
$A_RANDOM is odd
{% endif %}
{% if $(( $A_RANDOM%2 )) == 0 %}
{% for n in 1 2 3 $aux %}
\$myarray[$((n-1))]: ${myarray[$((n-1))]}
/etc/passwd field #$n: $(grep $USER /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f$n)
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
{% for n in {1..4} %}
\$myarray[$((n-1))]: ${myarray[$((n-1))]}
/etc/group field #$n: $(grep ^$USER /etc/group | cut -d: -f$n)
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}


$ ./shtpl < /tmp/test
6535
6535 is odd
$myarray[0]: a
/etc/group field #1: myusername
$myarray[1]: b
/etc/group field #2: x
$myarray[2]: c
/etc/group field #3: 1001
$myarray[3]: d
/etc/group field #4:
```

More info on my [github](https://github.com/mlorenzo-stratio/shtpl)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution that safely supports full shell scripting.

*template.sh*

```sh
#!/bin/sh

EOF=EOF
exec cat <<EOF | sh
cat <<EOF
$(cat $1 | \
    sed 's|`|\\`|g' | \
    sed 's|\$|\\\$|g' | \
    sed "s|${OPEN:-<%}|\`eval echo |g" | \
    sed "s|${CLOSE:-%>}|\`|g")
$EOF
EOF
```

Simply run the following on any file you want to template.

```sh
sh template.sh file.txt.tmpl
```

*file.txt.tmpl*

```
uname: <% $(uname) %>
pwd: <% `pwd` %>
ls: $(ls)
df: `df`
SHELL: <% $SHELL %>
HOME: <% ${HOME} %>
USER: $USER
PATH: ${PATH}
```

The output would be something like the following.

```
uname: Linux
pwd: /home/clayrisser
ls: $(ls)
df: `df`
SHELL: /usr/bin/zsh
HOME: /home/clayrisser
USER: $USER
PATH: ${PATH}
```

If you want to write the templated file, simply redirect the output to a new file.

```sh
sh template.sh file.txt.tmpl > file.txt
```

You can change the open and close characters by setting `OPEN` and `CLOSE`.

*file.txt.tmpl*

```
uname: {{ $(uname) }}
pwd: {{ `pwd` }}
ls: $(ls)
df: `df`
SHELL: {{ $SHELL }}
HOME: {{ ${HOME} }}
USER: $USER
PATH: ${PATH}
```

```sh
OPEN="{{" CLOSE="}}" sh template.sh file.txt.tmpl
```