# Is it possible with IPTABLES to ACCEPT a service by NAME like ssh or only by PORT?

Tags: ssh, iptables, port, port-forwarding, service

I have a local machine in my network `192.168.0.30` and i `ssh` over `port 12121`, setting in my `sshd_config` file.

I done changes to `iptables`:

`/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 12121 -j ACCEPT`

`/sbin/iptables -P INPUT DROP`

So my machine accept only input from `port 12121` now, this works i can ssh into it

On this machine i run an `autossh script` from a `service`, for `remote port forwarding` to get access from outside.

Command in my script:

```
/usr/bin/autossh -f -NT -o "ExitOnForwardFailure=yes" -R 20000:localhost:12121 \
-l [REMOTE-USER] [REMOTE-IP] -p 11111 -i [REMOTE-KEY]
```

When i try to connect it won't work, normal i accept only `12121` in iptables

So i add this to my iptables:

`/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 20000 -j ACCEPT`

And even if i dont need this because it's the input port from the remote machine:

`/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 11111 -j ACCEPT`

Local ssh works remote ssh not.

When i check the my service with:

`systemctl status mysshservice`

I see all `exited status codes`, and the `restart` from the service and i see my `autossh` command with my options but i do see a second line with `-L` with a different port selected by `autossh` like `48328` so i do.

`/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 48328 -j ACCEPT`

Now i can ssh from outside again.

I have 2 questions now about `iptables`.

Is it possible to a accept the service by name, without a given port like
`ACCEPT ALL SSH CONNECTIONS` ?, so only ssh works without to `ACCEPT` every `PORT` i need.

My problme is the remote port changes every day so i have to generate new `ACCEPT RULES every day`.

When i work with autossh, `do i need a script to grep/awk/sed` the `-R and -L ports every day`, or is there an other solution for?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to achieve, but it seems that you complicate things for *no* reason.

Comment: Want to block all accept ssh, i search the stacksides and found only port blocking with iptables. you got a solution for me where i am not so complicate, ty?

Comment: Is it better to use fail2ban?

Comment: you could have the iptables rules in a file, and then template in whatever the port is today via some templating language prior to applying the updated rules for the updated port

Comment: what do you mean with templating language? bash script?

Comment: to  my first question i can block only ports with iptables right?

Comment: @thrig you mean this with template https://serverfault.com/questions/287688/templating-with-linux-in-a-shell-script ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use service names from `/etc/services` but internally `iptables` works with `port numbers`, only translated from this file since `tcp/udp` protocol headers use numbers not strings for ports.

Moreover there are no names for all port numbers since service names just conventionality http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers

Also a `service name` is anchored to only one port number at a time.

It does not working as you want.

Comment: Ok i see only some give standard ports in /etc/service but not new one, like when i create with autossh or ssh right?

Comment: Correct; `/etc/services` lists only the standard/conventional port numbers as assigned by IANA.  Anything you run on a nonstandard port has to be managed by you, even if it's "standard software listening on nonstandard port".  edit: as gapsf says, it can also be edited if you want to use a local service at a relatively fixed port number!

Comment: /etc/service is a fixed list, simply copy of original from IANA. But you can add something yours if it helps to you

Comment: The list will not helps me, but the answer was usefull, i will try a little more but not to much :) with a script/template, grep what i need and update iptables, thanks again^^

Comment: Just use fixed listen port for autossh   autossh -M monitor_port -L local_port:localhost:remote_port user@host

Comment: Fixed ports is not possible, i got a range of give ports, it's to much to explain..